# Issue with cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource method

Tags: ios, uitableview

My problem is the following: I assign a mutable array to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so that it displays each array object in a cell. So far so good, the cells are displayed as expected. Now i want a display (according to a condition) a `UILabel` in the first cell, so that the other mutable array objects will be shifted to the second cell, and third, etc.
The issue is that, when i test that condition, and it's true, the `UILabel` is displayed in the first cell **with the first object**. So actually, two elements are in the same cell, which is not what i expect. I want (when the condition is true) to shift all the elements, so that they will be displayed from the second cell in order to leave the first cell to the `UIlabel`.

My relevant code which doesn't give me what i expect, is this:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


     UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"any-cell"];


 // Add and display the Cell     
      cell.tag = [indexPath row];
      NSLog(@"cell.tag= %i",cell.tag);
      //test the condition, if it's ok, then add the label to the first cell
      if ([self isNoScoreLabelDisplayed] && cell.tag==0) {
        UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, 50)];
        [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [cell addSubview:lbl];
      }
    cell.tag = [self isNoScoreLabelDisplayed]?[indexPath row]+1:[indexPath row];//here i wanted to shift the tags in case the condition is true, so that all the elements will be displayed from the second cell. But seems not doing what i want :(


      //
      if (indexPath.row < cellList.count) {

            [cell addSubview:[cellList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];//cellList is the mutable array from which i get all the elements to display in the cells

      }else{

            [cell addSubview:nextButton];
      }


      return cell;
}
```

Am i missing something in my logic? thanx in advance.

Comment: as far as i understand it you would like something like a header - why not use the headerview of the table for this?

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply. Actually the header is doing something else, it's displaying the name of my game. No way to use the header :))

Comment: Where is `cell` being created? Can you expand that code?

Comment: @ctrahey: I expanded my code, the cell is created in the same datasource method, please check it :)

Comment: Thanks. Just a caveat: remember to properly clean up in your cell's `prepareForReuse` method, or use two different re-use pools for the two styles of cells (better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert your label's text as a first element in your container and check for it. This way you will save yourself any need for index offsets and further complications of your code.

E.g.

```
[cellList insertObject:@"Label name" atIndex:0];
if ([cell tag] == 0) {
    // add required label
}
else {
    // do whatever you do for your standard cells, getting them with [cellList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}
```

Comment: Thanx for reply, can you please clarify more?

Comment: What you mean by `// add required label`. Do you mean add the label to the `cell:addSubview` ? something like this: `[cell addSubview:myLabel];` ?

Comment: No, add it like you add it in your code (create a label, set its text from `[cellList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]` & add it as a subview to the cell).

Comment: In this case, `atIndex:0` will remove the actual value and put the `UILabel` instead. Is there any way to shift all the values and insert in the first index?

Comment: It will not remove it, it will shift all elements. [`If index is already occupied, the objects at index and beyond are shifted by adding 1 to their indices to make room.`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: `insertObject:atIndex:`doesn't work with `addObjectsFromArray:`, i remember that i use this method to fill in the mutable array used later by `cellForRowAtIndex`

Comment: Just insert the string for the label after you've prepared your mutable array

Answer (score 1):

You are associating the indexPath.row directly with your model indexes, when they should be offset for the "title" cell.

```
if (indexPath.row && (indexPath.row - 1) < cellList.count) {
            [cell addSubview:[cellList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1]];
} else {
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. Don't worry about the `FALSE` check of the variable state, i checked it already, and when it's `FALSE`, the UILabel is not displayed at all, and all goes fine. My issue still in the `TRUE` state of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use two cell identifiers for this, one for the LabelCell and one for the regular ArrayCell, this will clear things up for u, and u won't get a cell with a label and object.

Also I don't really know what u r doing, but it looks as u adding subViews to a cell every time, but u don't remove them anywhere. Don't forget that the cell get reused...

Answer (score 1):

Hi it seems to me that you check the label condition then you add the same the object in the mutablearray because your indexPath.row==0 < cell.count for the first row.

```
cell.tag = [self isNoScoreLabelDisplayed]?[indexPath row]+1:[indexPath row];//here i wanted to shift the tags in case the condition is true, so that all the elements will be displayed from the second cell. But seems not doing what i want :(
```

so the code above simply set your cell tag equal to indexpath.row + 1 if you have to display the label but the code below (remembering that the first time indexPath.row == 0, and so even if you displayed the label) add the same the array object :-)

```
if (indexPath.row < cellList.count)
```